# Associação condição E como formatação ente intervalos númericos

Tags: microsoft-excel

Gostaria de um dica de como faço para viabilizar a equação abaixo:

```
=SE(E($Q1744=W10;8>=$R1744<=12,99);1;0)
```

Comment: O que tem de "inviável" nela? Seria bom explicar o que quer fazer, e qual o problema encontrado.

Comment: Um problema ai é você estar misturando >= e =< na mesma expressão, em geral, tem que separar em 2 condições diferentes. (Python é uma exceção, permite 1 > x > 7 por exemplo.

Comment: Não entendi... Ela é inviável?

Comment: O título do assunto e a explicação do seu problema estão bem confusos e incoerentes. Sugiro que os refaça para ficar mais claro para a comunidade o objetivo do tópico.

Answer (score 0):

Reavalie o segundo argumento lógico da função `=E` ([`8>=$R1744<=12,99]`). Se separarmos em 2 equações separadas temos:

```
R1744 <= 8
R1744 <= 12,99
```

Meio redundande, não acha? Mas talvez vc queira dizer que é um número entre 8 e 12,99 ([`8<=$R1744<=12,99]`). De qualquer forma, separe os termos lógicos, assim:

```
=SE(E($Q1744=W10;8<=$R1744;$R1744<=12,99);1;0)
```